# How to sort array and create new sorted array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

have array `[{id: 5}, {id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 0}]` i wanna create sorted another array `[{id: 0}, {id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 5}]`. How i can do this with function `filter`?

Comment: Why would you use `filter` for that?!

Comment: Why would `sort` and `new array` requires the use of `filter`?

Comment: Look at the [Array.prototype.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) function.

Comment: Sort will do.. `array.sort( (a,b) => a.id > b.id )`

Comment: @RajeshDan `a.id - b.id` (negative and positive not true and false) :D

Comment: Yeah.. :D but again previous works for this scenario.. Thanks @ibrahimmahrir

Comment: how sort date object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the sort method of the array to sort the values

```
array.sort(function(a, b) {
return a.id- b.id;
});
```

Comment: how do it with date object

Comment: Convert the date to milliseconds, should help you

Comment: Use a.date.getTime()-b.date.getTime()